# What are bagel chips?

Tags: bagels

[This](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/food-network-kitchens/oven-fried-chicken-recipe.html) recipe for southern-fried chicken mentions something called "bagel chips."

What exactly are bagel chips, and how do you make them? All I can find are recipes for it or places that sell something in a bag that resembles potato chips.

Comment: I was going to suggest melba toast as an alternative ... but the recipe already says that.

Comment: @Joe feel free to explain what melba toast is too :)

Comment: it's really thin toast ... dried out so much that it's shelf stable for months, like croutons (although, it's used more like a cracker).  The original way of making it was to take a piece of toast, slice it through the middle (so it's 1/2 the thickness of the original slice), and then toast the inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the first answer, but feel the need to clarify the 'pepperoni' reference. Yes, they are slices of bagels. However, if you cut a bagel vertically in half as it rests flat and treat each half as if you were slicing a curved salumi, all of your chips will be inconsistently thick on one edge and thin on the other (thanks to the properties of a torus). While that leaves them all consistently round, their thickness varies, which makes evenly toasting them a problem.

The more conventional approach: take the whole bagel as it lies flat on the cutting board, and slice it vertically but thinly from one side to the other. There will be much more variation in chip shape, but it's much easier to maintain the right thickness for even toasting. This is also why most (if not all) bags of chips are sliced in this manner, and you see such wild variation of circles, ovals, etc in chip shape.

A Gildy's Blade or a tightly serrated bread knife will do the job. Along with a bit of patience.

Comment: The difference between the thickness of one edge and the other will be negligible, especially if you're cutting them 1/8" thick. They always toast fairly evenly for me, and anyway, the toasting for ashes999's application doesn't even need to be particularly even. They'll be crumbling up the chips to use as breading, so as long as the chips are dry (baked through) they'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Bagel chips are just bagels sliced into little rounds- think bagel pepperoni. I know of a few different ways to make them, but generally you just bake or toast the rounds (you can butter each slice a little bit or drizzle olive oil over them before baking) until crispy. Here's a good [recipe.](http://www.foodiewithfamily.com/2013/04/22/garlic-bagel-chips-make-ahead-mondays/) I'd personally recommend using egg bagels, they have an excellent flavor.